# splitting up attribute options by letter in layered navigation

Tags: magento

I have a custom attribute, that is a drop down option.

There are several options to chose from, approx 100

What I'm looking to do, is rather have a long list of these options in the layered navigation, is to possibly have them grouped by letter.

such as A-G, H-L etc

Is this possible to do? Has anyone done this before?

I'm using Magento v1.6.1

Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do -- can you please clarify? Perhaps create a mock image of what you want and show us. I have too many questions to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Ok to clarify. I have almost 100 options in an attribute named 'Gases'. These are e.g. Ammonia, Carbon Dioxide all the way to those that start with X. There are almost 100 gases, which in the layered nav looks ugly. What I'm looking to do, is to have the attribute in the leftnav, display A-K etc clicking on this A-K link, will display all those products that have the gas attribute that starts with A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J and K

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Are you using jQuery or Prototype, and is it acceptable to have the frontend handle hiding/showing the attributes correctly?

Comment: Hi. I have both jQuery and Prototype. But I'll be happy using either. What do you mean by hiding/showing the attributes?

Comment: @zschuessler would you be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this in your own layered navigation template code:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5500/

Although that is a very old post, the code works fine in recent Magento versions. You'll have to roll your sleeves up and write your own loop to put things into your groups but the above approach should get you started.

Comment: Excellent. I'll have a look at this!